# how to prevent doubling the input file if the user opened it and closed it without choosing a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want when the user chooses a file there is another input file is created but with my code when the user open it and close it without choosing a file then he opened it again and chose one there are 2 inputs are created if he opened and closed 3 times then chose one there are 4 inputs are created.
if he chose a file from the first time there is just 1 is created

```
<div class="gal-stf">
    <input class="plus-n" type="file">
      <p class="bt"></p>
  </div>
      <div class="ad-photo" style="display: none;">

      <div class="gal-stf">
    <input class="plus-n" type="file">
          <p></p>
  </div>
          </div>
```

```
$(".gal").on("click", ".plus-n", function () {

              var el = $(this).val();
              $(this).change(function () {
        $('.gal').append($('.ad-photo .gal-stf').last().clone(false));
                  $(this).prop('disabled' , 'disabled');
                  $(this).siblings('p').text(this.value);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's happening because you are binding event handler on each click, so `3` click means 3 different handlers and each will fire when change event happened. Instead of listening click event directly listen to change event using event delegation.

```js
$(".gal").on("change", ".plus-n", function() {
  $('.gal').append($('.ad-photo .gal-stf').last().clone(false));
  $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  $(this).siblings('p').text(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gal">
  <div class="gal-stf">
    <input class="plus-n" type="file">
    <p class="bt"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="ad-photo" style="display: none;">

    <div class="gal-stf">
      <input class="plus-n" type="file">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```